# InputStream converted into String consider the high performance

Tags: java, performance, rest

I have created the rest-client java code and convert XML response into String. I have found three ways to convert that response.

```java
HttpURLConnection....
....
InputStream in = new GZIPInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
```

`Gzip` response covert into InputStream using above line. Then I have found following 3 methods to convert into String.

**1 Method**

```java
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
int length = 0;
while ((length = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    baos.write(buffer, 0, length);
}

String response =new String(baos.toByteArray());
```

**2 Method**

```java
String response = "";
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
String output;
while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
    response =output;
}
```

**3 Method**

```java
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int c; (c = in.read()) >= 0;)
    sb.append((char) c);
String response = sb.toString();
```

I need to know which is the best way to read XML response, considering the high performance / availability (to reduce response time). This code will going to used around 50-100 request per second with parallel process. Please advise me.

Comment: See this [article](https://www.baeldung.com/convert-input-stream-to-string). And perform a benchmark analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your answer.

I did a simple code that does all performance tests for you:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

public class Main {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  // Your code here!
  String response = "";
  DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");

  //STEP 1
  InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream("MYSTREAMASDasdasdSJKDFJASLKFJKSDLFJLKSADJFKSJDKAFJKSDJFLKSDJLKFJLKSDFJLKSDJLKLAKSDJLJKFSDKJADFSLJKLKJSDALJKALJKS adkaslkdajslkdjkaslkdjlaks\nasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdas".getBytes());

  System.out.println("FIRST OPTION");
  long beginTime = System.nanoTime();
  //System.out.println("begin -" + beginTime);
  for (int i = 0; i < 500000; i++) {
   ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
   int length = 0;
   while ((length = in .read(buffer)) != -1) {
    baos.write(buffer, 0, length);
   }
   response = new String(baos.toByteArray());
  }
  long endTime = System.nanoTime();
  System.out.println(endTime - beginTime);

  //STEP 2
  System.out.println("SECOND OPTION");
  beginTime = System.nanoTime();
  for (int i = 0; i < 500000; i++) {
   response = "";
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( in ));
   String output;
   while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
    response = output;
   }
  }
  endTime = System.nanoTime();
  System.out.println(endTime - beginTime);

  System.out.println("THIRD OPTION");
  beginTime = System.nanoTime();
  for (int i = 0; i < 500000; i++) {
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   for (int c;
    (c = in .read()) >= 0;)
    sb.append((char) c);
   response = sb.toString();
  }
  endTime = System.nanoTime();
  System.out.println(endTime - beginTime);
 }
}
```

Here you have the results for 500K loop executions :

- FIRST OPTION 284684443 Milliseconds
- SECOND OPTION 1331922335 Milliseconds
- THIRD OPTION 16031272 Milliseconds

> As you will see, **Third option is the fastest here.**

[Here](https://paiza.io/projects/Gq7M-WJFN7575dLvN8pe_A) is the running example

Comment: Thanks. This very useful for me.

Comment: @ThusithaIndunil if you consider the question as solved, please accept the answer to close it!! thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I have run my code using **Jemeter - Java Request**, According to the stats 1 Method is showing the best performance comparing others. This test run with actual HTTP call and convert that response into String.

**Method 01**
Successfully performed action: FULL: 1.393 Sec, CONVERT: **0.001** Sec

**Method 02**
Successfully performed action: FULL:1.502 Sec, CONVERT: **0.021** Sec

**Method 03**
Successfully performed action: FULL: 1.709 Sec, CONVERT: **0.015** Se

Beach mark code here:-
https://github.com/idthusitha/ride-test

Comment: The performances are different here. I think they are strongly afffected by the line sizes and number of lines depending on which one u use. I reccomend you to make some more tests to just ensure you fit all your requirements with one of them